# Permutation importance larger than 1 for linear regression R^2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using sklearns `permutation_importance` to estimate the importance of my independent variables. The model I am fitting is a linear Regression.
The permutation importance the model returns looks like this: `[0.7939618  3.6692722  0.02936469]`.

The permutation importance is defined to be the difference between the baseline metric and metric from permutating the feature column.

In my case, I think that the baseline metric is the R^2 value if I do not permutate any variables (baseline R^2~0.86). How is it possible that I obtain a value of `3.66` for one of my features in this case? If I manually permutate this feature and recalculate R^2, I get a value of ~ 0.18, so the feature importance would be ~0.68 if I am not mistaken.

If anyone could explain to my why I am observing these high feature importance values, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I would say that one possibility might be found in the fact that r2 can be negative in case the model is worse than the mean model (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) for reference).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that as well, but like I said, if I manually permutate the column the R^2 value only drops to 0.18.. and not to -2.7 something